# StoreFront Wordpress theme: How can i create a new Home page with Custom design same as template

Tags: theme-development, themes

I am getting too frustrated while creating new home page using template in Storefront theme. https://wordpress.org/themes/storefront/.

With the help of this https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/
i tried bt not getting success.. anyone can tell me how can i do this without plug-in..

I want to change home page , and want to show my custom template home page. –

**Template Script**

```
<?php
/**
 * Template name: Homepage My Custom
 *
 * @package storefront
 */

get_header(); ?>

    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
            **My Custom Home Template**
        </main><!-- #main -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step in modifying a theme, is [creating a child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes#How_to_Create_a_Child_Theme).

Now that you have a theme that is basically the same as the original, you can simply copy files of the original theme that you want to modify into exactly the same relative location as in the original theme and modify them to whatever you need. In your specific case, after locating the page template for the home page and copying it you can just modify the code in it and there is no need to create a new one.

Comment: hi thankx.. I did not tries Child theme. But i think i have find out the issue.. My template name is not listing in Wordpress admin menu .. I tried with Twenty twelve bt same issue , template name not is in List during add page.

Comment: In any case you should do a child theme otherwise you will loose your changes when you upgrade the theme. As for not finding the template, have you tried to place it in the root directory of the theme?

Answer (score 0):

First create a new page in theme directory

example `template-newhomepage.php` (Copy of `template-homepage.php`)

Change theme name to

```
Template name: New Homepage
```

Next step is to Change:

```
do_action( 'homepage' );
```

to

```
do_action( 'homepagenew' );
```

For create homepagenew hook in hook.php

Follow directory path:

```
/wp-content/themes/storefront/inc/structure
```

add this code under homepage hook:

```
add_action( 'homepagenew', 'storefront_homepagenew_content', 10 );
add_action( 'homepagenew', 'storefront_product_categories', 20 );
add_action( 'homepagenew', 'storefront_recent_products',  30 );
add_action( 'homepagenew', 'storefront_featured_products', 40 );
add_action( 'homepagenew', 'storefront_popular_products', 50 );
add_action( 'homepagenew', 'storefront_on_sale_products', 60 );
```

Next thing we have to do is add below code in template-tag.php in same directory:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'storefront_homepagenew_content' ) ) {
/**
  * Display homepage content

* Hooked into the `homepage` action in the homepage template

* @since  1.0.0
  * @return  void
  */
function storefront_homepagenew_content() {

while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
   get_template_part( 'content', 'newhomepage' );

endwhile; 
// end of the loop.

}
}
```

Now Create a Content-newhomepage.php file replica of content-homepage.php in theme directory

```
/wp-content/themes/storefront/
```

Now you can create a New homepage in WordPress admin and assign template "New Homepage" to this page.

Comment: Modifying themes without making a child theme is a big no no

Comment: You are right, but as per the question the user wants to do the customization within the same theme.

Comment: Many times a user want to do the wrong thing. You are more then welcome to give him the rope to hang himself, but at least tell him that in the end of the process he is going to die ;) ( the end here - theme upgrade)

Comment: I know not a Good Solution. But its not a Bad solution that some one mark -1 . i agree with you. With your solution we can customize theme, if we do not want to update Theme.. +1 for you.